# How do I run a custom script when I view a website?

Tags: javascript

For example, I want to copy text from this website: http://cafe.naver.com/4korean
But they have disabled right click menu as well as any kind of text selection on the website
After a little searching in Google I found this script: http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/61326
which is supposed to disable the protection on their website
However, I am not able to figure out how to run this code
I pressed F12 and went to the Chrome console, but when paste and run the code, I just get the message `undefined` (which I am sure was some other red coloured error message when I had tried the same thing just this morning)
I am not sure if there is any problem with the script, or with the way I am running it.
Please help.
Thank you.

PS: I am not sure how to tag this question. I think the script is javascript but I am not sure. Please provide some suggestions on this as well. Thanks.

Comment: see greasemonkey https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/  and ya it's for firefox, you need to search for chrom

Comment: so it's not possible to do this without installing something else?

Comment: You can do anything you need from your browser's web inspector/development tools. But, you have to know what you're doing.

Comment: Is that the tool described here (for Chrome)? :  https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/

Comment: This is how I reached the console; I thought the way to run javascript was just copy/paste the code in the console. If that's not it, can I make the script provided in my question to run on this page, without installing anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Hers is the [Link](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/501/re-enable-right-click-when-web-pages-turn-it-off/) which will let you study how to re-enable right click on website, try it for once.
Hers is the anothere one [Link2](http://www.wikihow.com/Successfully-Right-Click-Web-Pages-That-Don%27t-Allow-Right-Clicks)

Besides, that there come a plugin for Mozilla [Mozilla Right to click](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/righttoclick/) and chrome [Chrome Allow Right Click](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-right-click/hompjdfbfmmmgflfjdlnkohcplmboaeo?hl=en), you can have it whatever you wants.